# Tomcat handling of sessions on JRuby/Rails app

Tags: session, tomcat, jrubyonrails

Running our JRuby/Rails application locally on rails/rack, the session id is reset/renewed in
session/abstract_store.rb using the DestroyableSession destroy method.
Each new request coming in, using the same browser, will generate a new session id.

When the application is deployed to Tomcat and a request is completed.
If the same browser window is used and a subsequent transaction is submitted, the session
id remains the same between transactions and no new session id is created.

How does running on Tomcat cause the difference in session handling?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a servlet container designed to solve these problems for you. In particular it sets the JSESSIONID cookie to track the current session from the user.